# Update the RegionalSettings in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, regional-settings

I'm currently creating a number of sites in a SharePoint online environment. I'm doing this with the client object model. I want to automatically change the timezone of the site. In the userinterface this is possible, see the image below.

[image]

With the client object model, it is possible to retrieve the RegionalSettings of the web via Web.RegionalSettings. Unfortunately it is not possible to set any of the RegionalSettings properties because they are all readonly. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.regionalsettings_members.aspx)

I also tried setting the locale when creating the site by setting the language property of the WebCreationInformation class, but that's not what I want to do. I want to keep the language of my site in English and only change the TimeZone.

Is there any other way to accomplish this, or is the only way setting it manually in the UI?

Answer (score 2):

When the fields are read-only, you can't change them as you have found out. But it's likely that this will change in the near future since Microsoft spend a lot of resources to extend the Office 365 API's

Comment: Let's hope they implement it in the API soon :) Meanwhile I will search for another way to accomplish it.